Views counter randomly resets to 0 — What could be causing this issue?
I have a small news website with thousands of articles. I'm using NextJS (version 14 with pages directory) on the frontend and Strapi on the backend. Each article has "views" field in Strapi, which is 0 by default. Then I increment it like that:
export const Article = ({ data }) => {
    const [views, setViews] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        async function addViews() {
            setViews("loading")
            const article = await getArticle(data.id)
            if (article) {
                await updateArticle(data.id, article.views + 1)
                setViews(article.views + 1)
            }
        }
        addViews()
    }, [data])

    return <article>

        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
        
        {(views && views !== "loading") && <span>{views}</span>}

        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content }} />

    </article>

}

Everything works fine, but sometimes views counter of some articles just randomly starts from 0 again. I know the code is far from perfect, I'm actually very new in the coding. What should I look into to improve it?

It could happen if the useEffect got called twice and first fetch result overwitten the second one. A common approach is to add a flag to prevent race conditions using hooks like useEffect:
export const Article = ({ data }) => {
    const [views, setViews] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        // a flag to determine if an update is necessary
        let isMounted = true

        async function addViews() {
            if (!isMounted) return

            setViews("loading")
            const article = await getArticle(data.id)

            // if the VDom is no longer mounted, skip the update phase
            if (isMounted && article) {
                await updateArticle(data.id, article.views + 1)
                setViews(article.views + 1)
            }
        }
        addViews()

        // cleanup function, if the hook will be triggered again, set the flag to false
        return () => isMounted = false
    }, [data])

    return <article>
        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
        {(views && views !== "loading") && <span>{views}</span>}
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content }} />
    </article>
}

